# Integration: Integrating then substituting a number has a different answer to substituting a number then integrating; for trigonometric functions

Tags: integration

This might be a very dumb question but I am really stuck as to why this happens. Now, the answer to the integral
$$B_n = 2 \int_0^1 k\sin(3\pi x)\sin(n\pi x) dx \qquad (k = 0.01,  
 n=1,2,3,...)$$
is $k$ when $n=3$ and $0$ when $n\neq3 $.

But when I try to solve for a general solution I get
$$
\begin{align}
B_n &= 2k\int_0^1 \frac12[\cos(3\pi x-n\pi x)-\cos(3\pi x+n\pi x)]dx
\\ &= k\int_0^1 \cos(3\pi x-n\pi x)-cos(3\pi x+n\pi x)dx
\\ &= k[\frac{1}{3\pi - n\pi}\sin(3\pi x - n\pi x) - \frac{1}{3\pi+ n\pi}\sin(3\pi x+ n\pi x)]_0^1 
\\ &= k(\frac{1}{3\pi - n\pi}\sin(3\pi - n\pi) - \frac{1}{3\pi+ n\pi}\sin(3\pi+ n\pi)
)\end{align}
$$
which gives $0$ for all integer $n$. 
Why is that?

Comment: Would there be a time when $3\pi -n\pi = 0$?  That would make dividing by it hard.

Comment: General advice: When a general computation disagrees with what you know about a special case, plug that special case into the general computation and see what happens. In your situation, the special case with the disagreement is $k=3$, and once you plug that into the general computation, you'd immediately see zeros in the denominators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that  $\dfrac{1}{3\pi - n\pi}$ is not defined at $n=3$. So you need to solve the integral for $n=3$ separately. 
When  $n=3$, we have 
$$k\int_0^1 \cos(3\pi x-n\pi x)-\cos(3\pi x+n\pi x)dx=k\int_0^1 \cos(0)-cos(6\pi x)dx=k\int_0^1 1-\cos(6\pi x)dx.$$
Can you complete this?

Comment: Thanks so much! I completely forgot about the undefined part.